# Is Textmate like Ruby Markers "#=>" in notepad++ available?

Tags: notepad++, ruby, textmate

I use *Notepad++* to write Ruby code. Now sometimes to test some Ruby features I used to go `IRB` to see how that works. Can I get the same flavor in *Notepad++* itself,like *Textmate* editor as below?

```
x = 10
y = 20
x + y #=> 30
```

Does *Notepad++* have any such plugin to produce output with `#=>` like *Textmate*?